# List of all .txt file

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt4

Hi
I want to write a program that give a path in my system and goes to that path and search in that path and sub-directory of path and list all of .txt file . 
please help me .
thanks .

Comment: So what are you asking about, C, C++ or Qt? Each one would use a different approach. System functions for C, boost for C++ and Qt provides this internally.

Answer (score 3):

The Following code will list all your files in "C:\Windows\System32" directory (SYSDIR for XP system). Add it in your code however you want.

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
        dir = opendir ("c:\\Windows\\System32");
if (dir != NULL) {

  /* print all the files and directories */
  while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
    printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
  }
  closedir (dir);
} else {
  /* Can not open directory */
  perror ("");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: This solution does not care wildcards

Comment: Make dir a parameter and call the function recursively to handle subdirectories.  And pass dir to perror.

Comment: I am working with Visual Studio 2010 . How can I use dirent.h ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of type `QDir`. This can be used to navigate to the desired folder, e.g. by using `dirobj.cd("/mypath/somewhere")`. Then use `dirobj.entryList(QStringList("*.txt", "*.otherext", ...)` to retrieve a list of the files found.